# minimal linux install for vmware

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-player, barebone

I want to install minimal version of some distro for vmware.

I only intend to use gedit, terminal, putty and chromium.
Copy paste and resize should work.

I had installed minimal ubuntu but on installing gnome-core all usual bloat was installed.
With any other linux distro or xfce in ubuntu copy/paste/resize does not work properly.

Any ideas for any version of linux or how to get minimal gnome ?

Comment: Gnome isn't "minimal". Instead, you should focus on your problems with the other desktop environments, which I do not have. Please name your distribution. Also, you could try LXDE.

Comment: I am okay with anything that is fast and vmtools works properly for it.

Comment: Ah, are you, by any chance, referring to a Linux environment running *inside* a VM? If so, please clarify in the question. What does the Ubuntu tag refer to?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Daniel for suggesting Lxde. It seems much faster than earlier full ubuntu installs. Steps I followed :

1. get ubuntu minimal 32bit.
2. selected command line install.

ubuntu Install done.

3. command "sudo apt-get install lxde-core" refer: http://lxlinux.com/#19 .
4. "sudo apt-get install gcc make linux-headers-`uname -r` -y"
5. installed lxdm, xorg
6. After installing vm tools I logout and login.

There was lot of trial and error but finally things are as expected.